# How to pause and resume download on Android loopj AsyncHttp library?

Tags: android, download, android-async-http, loopj

What is the best way of implement a download manager with loopj AsyncHttp android library?

The main use case I interested is a pause and resume individual binary downloads.

Regards.

Comment: Why are you not using `DownloadManager` class for this ?